# Can't hide colorbar in plotly express choropleth

Tags: python, plotly, choropleth, plotly-express

I have tried following the docs and various posts that discuss this and I have gotten nowhere. I am rendering the choropleth counties map from the plotly example, but I can't seem to figure out how to hide the colorbar. This is what I have tried:

```
import plotly.express as px
from urllib.request import urlopen
import json
import pandas as pd

with urlopen('https://raw.githubusercontent.com/plotly/datasets/master/geojson-counties-fips.json') as response:
  counties = json.load(response)
df = pd.read_csv("https://raw.githubusercontent.com/plotly/datasets/master/fips-unemp-16.csv",
                  dtype={"fips": str})
fig = px.choropleth(
  df,
  geojson=counties,
  locations='fips',
  color='unemp',
  color_continuous_scale="Viridis",
  range_color=(0, 12),
  scope="usa",
  labels={'unemp':'Unemployment'}
)
fig.update_layout(margin={"r":0,"t":0,"l":0,"b":0}, coloraxis=dict(showscale=False))
fig.update(layout_coloraxis_showscale=False)
fig.update_traces(showlegend=False)
fig.update(layout_showlegend=False)
fig.update_traces(showscale=False)
fig.show()
```

My result is always the same:

[image]

Comment: What version of plotly are you currently using? You don't need to upgrade to 5.1.0 as mentioned in the answer. 4.14.13 will also hide the color bar.

Comment: I am doing this on anvil.works, and I don't have control over the version. They are on 3.X I think. I am going to have to spin up a separate server to handle this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest you check your plotly version using

```
import plotly
plotly.__version__
```

If it is less than `5.1.0` then I suggest you update it using the following pip command

```
pip install -Iv plotly==5.1.0
```

I just used your code only and with this specific version of plotly i am getting a map without the colorbar